# Convert string to list of strings in python

Tags: python, json, string, dataframe, csv

I have a string extracted from a .csv which has this format:

```
str = "[point, contextual, point]"
```

What I wanna do is convert it to a list in the format:

```
str = ["point", "contextual", "point"]
```

How can I do it? I tried with `json.loads(str)` but I got the error:

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Comment: As a general point, it's best not to name something `str` as that's the name of the built-in string type.

Comment: Refer to the link below for a guideline: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/how-to-convert-string-representation-of-list-to-a-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use:

```
my_str = "[point, contextual, point]"
my_str[1:-1].split(', ') # remove first and last characters ([]) and split on ", "
```

*NB. don't use `str` as a variable name, this overwrites the `str`
builtin*

Comment: If input has many spaces, then use `re.split` and `,\s*` as separator

Answer (score 2):

You could use this expression : `str[1:-1].split(", ")`

By the way it is not recommended to give a variable the name of a python type.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use [yaml](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation):

```
import yaml
s = "[point, contextual, point]"
s = yaml.load(s, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
print(s)
```

**Output**

```
['point', 'contextual', 'point']
```

**Note:**

yaml is a third party module to install it do (at the command line):

```
pip install pyyaml
```

The yaml version of the code snippet above is `5.4.1`

Comment: AttributeError: module 'yaml' has no attribute 'FullLoader'

Comment: Whats your version  GhostOps?

Comment: mine is 3.13, and how do u update it? whats its name in pypi.org? sry cuz i haven't ever used yaml tho

Comment: @GhostOps Updated the answer, if you have already installed perhaps you have to use pip install --upgrade pyyaml

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```py
string = "[point, contextual, point]"
print(string[1:-1].split(', '))
```

Outputs:

```
['point', 'contextual', 'point']
```

Tell me if its okay for you...

Comment: what is the point of the comprehension? `split` already returns a list

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
>>> st = "[point, contextual, point]"
>>> st[1:-1]
[point, contextual, point]

>>> st[1:-1].split(',')
['point', ' contextual', ' point'] # <- you have space

>>> list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), st[1:-1].split(',')))
['point', 'contextual', 'point']
```

**why not `split(', ')`?**

```
>>> st = "[point,   contextual,     point]"
>>> st[1:-1].split(', ') 
['point', '  contextual', '    point']

>>> list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), st[1:-1].split(',')))
['point', 'contextual', 'point']
```

Comment: Why not just split on `', '` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Because that's not a valid JSON string, the `json.loads` doesn't work. You need to do it manually and you can not use `json` module for the string you have.

```py
st = "[point, contextual, point]"
lst = st[1:-1].split(', ')
```

On a side note, don't use `str` as a vairable: that's a builtin